# python tokenization UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, nlp

I'm trying to tokenize some documents but I have this error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position
>   6: ordinal not in range(128)

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('status2.csv'))
documents = df['status']

result = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in documents]
```

I think it's the unicode problem so I added

```
documents = unicode(documents, 'utf-8')
```

another error

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Series found

```
print documents

1      Brandon Cachia ,All I know is that,you're so n...
2      Melissa Zejtunija:HAM AND CHEESE BIEX INI??? *...
3                         .........Where is my mind?????
4      Having a philosophical discussion with Trudy D...
```

Answer (score 2):

`unicode` operates on strings or bytes, but `documents` is a pandas Series.

Maybe:

```
result = [nltk.word_tokenize(unicode(sent, 'utf-8')) for sent in documents]
```